# Ng-repeat over localStorage data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-local-storage, ng-storage

This is my partial view

```
<table class="table table-hover" ng-controller="emailViewController">
    <tbody>
    <tr >
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkAllEmail" ng-model="selectedEmail"/>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
            </a></td>
        <td><label ng-bind="add"></label></td>
        <td><label ng-bind="subject"></label></td>
        <td><label ng-bind="emailContent" ></label></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have this data stored in localStorage:

[image]

I want to ng-repeat over the values of the keys `ngStorage-add` and `ngStorage-subject`. I tried the following:

1) `<td><label ng-bind="add" ng-repeat="item in localStorage.getItem('ngStorage-add')"></label></td>`.

2) `ng-repeat="item in localStorage.getItem('ngStorage-add') track by value"`

It did not work however. Does anyone have ideas on how to achieve this?

**EDIT**

`emailViewController`:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var emailViewController = function (fetchDataService, $scope,$filter,$timeout, $localStorage) {

        $scope.to = [];

        var url = 'app/mock/emails.json';
        fetchDataService.getContent(url)
            .then(function(response){
                $scope.emails = response.data;
                $scope.loadEmails('Primary');

                angular.forEach($scope.emails, function(key) {
                   $scope.to.push(key.to);
                });
            });

          $scope.information = {
              add: [],
              subject: [],
              emailContent: []
            };

          $scope.typeaheadOpts = {
              minLength: 1
            };

           $scope.$on("decipher.tags.added", function(info, obj) {
              $timeout(function(){
                tagAdded(info, obj);
              });
            });

            function tagAdded(info, obj) {
              for (var i = 0; i < $scope.to.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.to[i] === obj.tag.name) {
                  $scope.to.splice(i, 1);
                } 
              }
            }

             $scope.close = function(){
                //console.log("hide");
                $('.modal').modal('hide');

            };

         $scope.loadEmails = function(searchCriteria){
             $scope.filteredEmails =  $filter('filterByCategory')
                                            ($scope.emails,searchCriteria);
         };

         $scope.submit = function (add, subject, emailContent) {

          if (! ($localStorage.add instanceof Array) ) {
                $localStorage.add = [];
            }

            $localStorage.add.push(add);

            if (! ($localStorage.subject instanceof Array) ) {
                $localStorage.subject = [];
            }

            $localStorage.subject.push(subject);

            if (! ($localStorage.emailContent instanceof Array) ) {
                $localStorage.emailContent = [];
            }

            $localStorage.emailContent.push(emailContent);
            //$scope.update();
         };


            $scope.clear = function() {
                 $scope.information.add = [];
                 $scope.information.subject = '';
                 $scope.information.emailContent = '';
                 }            

        $scope.$on('loadEmail',function(event,data){
          $scope.loadEmails(data);
        });
    };
    angular.module('iisEmail')
        .controller ('emailViewController',
        ['fetchDataService', '$scope','$filter', '$timeout', '$localStorage', emailViewController]);
}());
```

**ATTEMPT 1**

This is returning the array - `$localStorage.add`

This is returning the first element of the array (`a` in this case) - `$localStorage.add[0][0]`

**ATTEMPT 2**

I injected `$localStorage` in the directive that was loading the template. It still does not work.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var drafts = function ($localStorage) {
        return {
            templateUrl : "app/partials/draftsView.html"
        };
    };

    angular.module('iisEmail').directive("drafts", ['$localStorage', drafts]);
}());
```

**ATTEMPT 3**

I stored the `$localStorage` data in a controller variable and got ng-repeat to iterate over the variable.

```
<td><label ng-repeat="item in addition track by $index">
                {{item}}
        </label></td>
```

Doing so produces a result, but the entire array is appearing in one line. I want `a` to be displayed in one line, and `b` to be displayed in the next line.

**ATTEMPT 3 UPDATE**

This is the updated partial view

```
<table class="table table-hover" ng-controller="emailViewController">
    <tbody>
    <tr >
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkAllEmail" ng-model="selectedEmail"/>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
            </a></td>
        <td><label ng-repeat="item in addition track by $index">
                {{item}} 
        </label></td>
        <td><label ng-bind="subject"></label></td>
        <td><label ng-bind="emailContent" ></label></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**ATTEMPT 4**

I modified the partial view as follows, and achieved exactly what I was looking for. Now, values of the keys are displayed in new lines. However, they are being displayed like so:

```
`[a]
 [b]
 [c]`
```

I dont want the array symbol to be shown. Here is the modified partial view.

```
<table class="table table-hover" ng-controller="emailViewController">
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat = "(key, value) in addition" >
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkAllEmail" ng-model="selectedEmail"/>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
            </a></td>
        <td>  {{ value }} </td>
        <td><label ng-bind="subject"></label></td>
        <td><label ng-bind="emailContent" ></label></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**SOLUTION**

```
<table class="table table-hover" ng-controller="emailViewController">
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat = "(key, value) in localStorage.add" >
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkAllEmail" ng-model="selectedEmail"/>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
            </a></td>
        <td ng-repeat = "value in value">  {{value }} </td>
        <td><label ng-bind="subject"></label></td>
        <td><label ng-bind="emailContent" ></label></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: would you show your controller code?

Comment: @Shimbr Please take a look at the "EDIT" section of my question for the controller's code. Thanks

Comment: So I don't see where you pass you localstage to the scope - see my answer, I think it's relevent

Comment: I am passing `$localStorage` to the controller -  `angular.module('iisEmail')
        .controller ('emailViewController',
        ['fetchDataService', '$scope','$filter', '$timeout', '$localStorage', emailViewController]);`

Comment: right, but u don't pass the localStorage to the scope.

Comment: Don't you think I am doing that too. Look at line 3. @Shimbr

Comment: Do you mean I should inject `localStorage` to the directive that is loading the partial view? @Shimbr

Comment: Michelle, you were given the answer in code. The reason your code is failing is because you cannot access a local variable in your controller from anywhere outside that controller. Add the $localStorage property to the $scope object and it will work. Once again: `$scope.localStorage = $localStorage`.

Comment: I figured that out. Please take a look at the "attempt 3" section in my question. Do you have any ideas on how to make the items not appear in a single line?

Comment: would you provide the code where you stored the `$localStorage` data in a controller variable?

Comment: @Shimbr Yes. Here it is. `$scope.addition = $localStorage.add`;

Comment: ok, so now you have probably a `html` or `css` issue, please show your updated html code.

Comment: Please take a look at the "Attempt 3 update" section of my question

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage can only store string values, i believe you saved the JSON object into local storage by serializing it using **JSON.stringify()**

so, in order to get the JSON object from localstorage, you can use **JSON.parse()** function like below,

```
var add = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ngstorage-add'))
var subject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ngstorage-subject'))
```

then you can iterate over it.

Read more about [LocalStorage](http://htmldog.com/guides/javascript/advanced/localstorage/)

Comment: No. I am not saving a JSON object. I am just pushing the data entered by the user into the `add` array like so: `$localStorage.add.push(add)`

Comment: i never used angular localstorage service, still it remains same, localstorage can only have string values, i think the angular service internal dealing with the serialization and de-serialization, try to use $localStorage while getting the data too, like $localStorage.getItem('ngStorage-add') and see if it returns JSON object

Comment: When I console.log `$localStorage.add` I get the array that is stored in add ([["a"],["b"],["c"]]).

Answer (score 0):

In order your angular directive should work, you have to make it available to the scope, so you have to do in your controller, something like this:

```
.controller('Ctrl', function(
    $scope,
    $localStorage
){
    $scope.localStorage = $localStorage;
});
```

Comment: The directive has access to the `emailViewController`

Comment: Shim br is correct. Your html has no access to an object called `localStorage` unless you add it to the scope.

Comment: Please look at the "Attempt 2" section of my question.

Comment: No!!! that's not what I mean. you don't have to inject the `$localStorage` service only in your controller, and you did it already. now you need to pass it to the `$scope`, to make it available for the view.